# how to use jquery to dynamically build a .text node that contains multiple <span>

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to dynamically update `<h1>` text to include `<span></span>` tags.

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KerryRuddock/ms8fk3kq/7/) shows javascript that looks like this:

```
$("h1").text("Time Left:<span>" + padNum(glob.gameTimer) + "</span>Best:
<span>" + padNum(glob.bestTime) + "</span>Reaction Time:<span>" + 
padNum(glob.reactionTime) + "</span");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html` instead of `text`

```
$("h1").html("Time Left:<span>" + padNum(glob.gameTimer) + "</span>Best:<span>" + padNum(glob.bestTime) + "</span>Reaction Time:<span>" + padNum(glob.reactionTime) + "</span");
```

Comment: Cool, then don't forget to mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$("h1").html()` instead of `$("h1").text()`.